# How not to duplicate a method using react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a hook called useAnalytics that I use to send events from my Analytics.
Inside it I have two methods:

```
const fireScreenDisplayed = (props = {}) => {
  _checkScreenValidity()
  if (checkDone && done && !props.force) return
  setDone(true)
  publishCdmEvent(_buildEvent('ScreenDisplayed', props))
}

const fireScreenCompleted = (props = {}) => {
  _checkScreenValidity()
  if (checkDone && done && !props.force) return
  setDone(true)
  publishCdmEvent(_buildEvent('ScreenDisplayed', props))
}
```

As you can see they are the same changing only the name,
I made it so when I call the method in a component I can pass different parameters in the useAnalytics hook.

```
const { fireScreenDisplayed } = useAnalytics(SCREENS.START)
const { fireScreenCompleted } = useAnalytics(SCREENS.COMPLETED)
```

In this case I want to pass two different constants `SCREENS.START and SCREENS.COMPLETED`

As a way to improve my code I would like to find a way to not duplicate these methods, have only one inside my Hook and be able to pass different parameters in my component.

How do I do that?

Comment: Can you show a bit more about the `useAnalytics` hook? I don't understand what the `SCREENS.START` parameter in `useAnalytics(SCREENS.START)` is supposed to do and how that relates to the duplicate functions.

Comment: Why are you duplicating a function if the only thing that changes are the props received? You could have only one of then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've shown, i think you just need to delete one of the functions. If necessary, you can reference the remaining function multiple times.

```
const useAnalytics = () => {
  const handler = (props = {}) => {
     _checkScreenValidity()
     if (checkDone && done && !props.force) return
     setDone(true)
     publishCdmEvent(_buildEvent('ScreenDisplayed', props))
   }

  return {
    fireScreenCompleted: handler,
    fireScreenDisplayed: handler
  }
}
```

You mentioned wanting to be able to pass a constant into the hook, but i don't know what that constant is supposed to do. If you edit your question to include more details, i'll try to include that in my answer.